# Implementing a point class in Python

Tags: python, error-handling, point

So I'm trying to implement a point class which creates a point and then rotate, scale and translate the point. Here's what I've currently written.

```
class Point:
    '''
        Create a Point instance from x and y.
    '''
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    '''
        Rotate counterclockwise, by a radians, about the origin.
    '''
    def rotate(self, a):
        self.x0 = math.cos(this.a) * self.x - math.sin(this.a) * self.y
        self.y0 = math.sin(this.a) * self.x + math.cos(this.a) * self.y

    '''

        Scale point by factor f, about the origin.
    Exceptions
        Raise Error if f is not of type float.
    '''
    def scale(self, f):
        self.x0 = f * self.x
        self.y0 = f * self.y

    '''
        Translate point by delta_x and delta_y.
    Exceptions
        Raise Error if delta_x, delta_y are not of type float.
    '''
    def translate(self, delta_x, delta_y):
        self.x0 = self.x + delta_x
        self.y0 = self.y + delta_y

    '''
        Round and convert to int in string form.
    '''
    def __str__(self):
        return int(round(self.x))
```

Something in this code is generating an error. Now I haven't implementing error catching and I do have an error method at the top

```
class Error(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message
```

But how would I catch the error if a certain variable is not of type float?

Here's one of the if statements I'm using:

```
def __init__(self, x, y):
        if not isinstance(x, float):
            raise Error ("Parameter \"x\" illegal.")        
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
        if not isinstance(y, float):
            raise Error ("Parameter \"y\" illegal.")
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
```

But that gets me an indentation error. So how exactly can I print out an error message that says exactly which variable is causing the problem?

Comment: "Something in this code is generating an error." What is generating the error? (Hint: the error message tells you.)

Comment: Should not `self.x = 0` be `self.x = x` and `self.y = 0` be `self.y = y`?

Comment: The error says "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_A.py", line 17, in <module>
    print Point(0.0,1.0)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type int)
"

Comment: Why do you care about the variables are float?
If you want to make sure it is a number you could query if the variable is of a instance of a number type and if not throw a custom error by yourself...

Comment: your error is because you cast the return value of  __str__ to int and not to str

Comment: But str is supposed to round and convert to an int.

Comment: Can't you just use a [**`complex`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#complex) number?

Comment: @DavidRolfe: so why not just fix `__str__` to return a string instead of an integer? `__str__` **must** return a string. You can convert your int to a string if that's what you want to display.

Comment: @PeterWood: why would a `complex` number help here?

Comment: I don't think I can use complex numbers. With _str_ it is supposed to convert it into an int in string form however I'm only using self.x. Would I need to append self.y in there somewhere?

Comment: @MartijnPieters A complex number supports rotation, scaling, and translation.

Comment: @PeterWood: but that won't let the OP learn about classes, would it. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is that the purpose?

Comment: Now the error says AttributeError: Point instance has no attribute 'x' for the _str_ method.

Comment: @DavidRolfe: not if you don't want to. What do you expect `print(Point())` to produce?

Comment: @PeterWood: almost certainly.

Comment: It's supposed to produce a single point and then rotate, scale, and translate that point so I can draw different shapes.

Comment: Ok so it appears that the problem is with the return int(round(self.x)) because it's saying that x does not exist even though I'm sure I defined x earlier in my program.

Comment: Again, the _str_ method is supposed to round and convert to an int in string form but it keeps saying Point instance has no attribute 'x' for the str method. So why does it keep saying that? Is there something important I left out of my _str_ method?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to raise an exception, do it in the Point's initializer:

```
def __init__(self, x, y):
    if not isinstance(x, float) or not isinstance(y, float):
        raise Error("Point's coordinates must be floats.")
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
```

Or convert the coordinates to float:

```
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = float(x)
    self.y = float(y)
```

Comment: I used Error class here, cause you mention you have it defined, but it probably should be more specific Exception

Comment: Should self.x = x and self.y = y be inside the indentation because I keep getting an error with that line.

Comment: Ok it seems to be working for catching the error but what if I wanted the error message to say Parameter "x" illegal or Parameter "a" illegal and actually name which variable is causing the error.

Comment: @DavidRolfe in this case when we talk only about 2 variables x and y, just make the if statement more detailed.

Comment: I tried using two if statements and it keeps saying 
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Answer (score 0):

If the variable is not a float, you'll get a TypeError. Pretty much you can 'catch' these error like this;

```
try:
    pass # your stuff here.
except e as TypeError:
    print e # this means a type error has occurred, type is not correct.
```

Also, this would be worth reading for checking for correct types at the start with assert; https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingAssertionsEffectively